# Wordpress edit post/page screen is messed up

Tags: wordpress, web

I've transferred my wordpress website from a shared hosting to a linux VPS.
Everything is working fine instead of one thing. I'm getting realy weird pages for editing posts/pages.

I'm not sure how to name it and can't find anything on google about it, so I hope someone here can send me in the right direction.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja9Wc.png)

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're either missing some CSS files, or the paths to those CSS files are no longer valid on the new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance, looks like a browser caching issue. Try the following:

1. Clear browser cache/cookies etc. and restart the browser/PC
2. Check with a different browser
3. Depending on how you migrated (transferred) the site, it is possible that all files did not get transferred fully and/or the database did not get imported fully. If 1. and 2. above fail, delete everything from the VPS and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried all 3 the options (multiple times). Turned hidden files on with filezilla, tryd with only 1 ftp connection (just to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure when you check the network tab or console in `inspect element` on chrome, you will receive a lot of 404 errors because it is not able to load the required files for some reason.

What you can try is to add `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false)` into your `wp-config.php` file. What this does is load all the javascript files individually, instead of one concatenated file.

**Question:** Are you using the same domain on your VPS? Or are you accessing the site on your VPS through a different domain? If so, you might want to update your database to correspond with the domain you're testing with now. Because this can cause strange behavior as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This is the only line in my console: http://prntscr.com/ctfbcc. And yes, I'm using the same domainname.

Comment: And when you check the network tab and refresh the page?